# Map two string arrays without a switch

Tags: c#

I have two arrays that need to be mapped.  In code

```
var result = "[placeholder2] Hello my name is [placeholder1]";
var placeholder = { "[placeholder1]", "[placeholder2]", "[placeholder3]", "[placeholder4]" };
var placeholderValue = { "placeholderValue3", "placeholderValue2", "placeholderValue3" };

Array.ForEach(placeholder , i => result = result.Replace(i, placeholderValue));
```

given `i`, `placeholderValue` needs to be set in an intelligent way.  I can implement a switch statement.  The cyclomatic complexity would be unacceptable with 30 elements or so.  What is a good pattern, extension method or otherwise means to achieve my goal?

Comment: So, for every placeholder, you will attempt to replace it with each of `placeHolderValue1`, `placeholderValue2` and `placeholderValue3`?

Comment: Why not use an `IDictionary<string, string>`? This seems like a perfect use for it?

Comment: I was doing something similar not so long ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017160/efficient-template-population

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - Because that would be far too simple and elegant an idea!  Or, cause I didnt think of it.  I knew you guys would come through.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skipped null checks for simplicity

```
string result = "[placeholder2] Hello my name is [placeholder1]";
var placeHolders = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
    { "placeholder1", "placeholderValue1" }, 
    { "placeholder2", "placeholderValue2" } 
};

var newResult =  Regex.Replace(result,@"\[(.+?)\]",m=>placeHolders[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

Comment: Excellent, especially MatchEvaluator usage

Answer (score 0):

The smallest code change would be to just use a for loop, rather than a ForEach or, in your case, a ForEach taking a lambda.  With a for loop you'll have the index of the appropriate value in the `placehoderValue` array.

The next improvement would be to make a single array of an object holding both a placeholder and it's value, rather than two 'parallel' arrays that you need to keep in sync.

Even better than that, and also even simpler to implement, is to just have a `Dictionary` with the key being a placeholder and the value being the placeholder value.  This essentially does the above suggestion for you through the use of the KeyValuePair class (so you don't need to make your own).

At that point the pseudocode becomes:

`foreach(key in placeholderDictionary) replace key with placeholderDictionary[key]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to combine the placeholders with their values.

```
var result = "[placeholder2] Hello my name is [placeholder1]";
var placeholder = new[] { "[placeholder1]", "[placeholder2]", "[placeholder3]", "[placeholder4]" };
var placeholderValue = new[] { "placeholderValue1", "placeholderValue2", "placeholderValue3", "placeholderValue4" };
var placeHolderPairs = placeholder.Zip(placeholderValue, Tuple.Create);

foreach (var pair in placeHolderPairs)
{
    result = result.Replace(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
}
```